# How to perform exact match for folder name with prefix using ListObjectsV2 AWS S3 node js sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

Consider the below scenario in which I have faced the problem.

Let there be **documents** and **documentscopy** folder in S3 bucket.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: BucketName,
    MaxKeys: 500,
    Prefix: 'documents'
}

s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
});
```

Above code provides all files in both **documents** and **documentscopy**.

What code change I have to do in order to get **documents** only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add `/` to your `Prefix`.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: BucketName,
    MaxKeys: 500,
    Prefix: 'documents/'
}
```